# WSO2 Identity Server / Travelocity Authentication Test with OpenID

Tags: wso2, openid, identity

I would like to test a WSO2 Identity provider, indeed its federated IdP configured with OpenID, and I plan to test it with the Travelocity tool. I'm editing the travelocity.properties file in the WEB-INF configuration, setting the starting parameters to the following value:

```
EnableSAMLSSOLogin=false
EnableOpenIDLogin=true
EnableSAML2Grant=false
```

When stating the image in the Tomcat7 server, it accepts the new server configuration, but the code still activates the SAML authentication as primary SSO mechanism, throwing an error:

```
SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
Error when processing the authentication request! 
Please try login again.
```

Is it possible to deactivate SAML in this web tool, using only the OpenID stack?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are referring the passive authentication request (It is made when you access a protected page when there's no http session). For the travelocity sso sample it's not possible to deactivate the passive request with a configuration. However you can avoid that by accessing login page directly (http://[host]:[port]/travelocity.com/index.jsp) which is unprotected. From there you can use the OpenID login.